# turned up sound-system-loud

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ***"whilst the music may have been turned up sound-system-loud"*** mean in the following sentence? Does it mean "although it could have been a party with very loud music, it was a silent party"?

Context:

> The point was, though, that whilst the music may have been turned up
>   sound-system-loud, this was a silent rave in which participants each
>   listened to their favourite dance tracks on their own private iPods.

Comment: It means that the sound was very loud, but it was restricted to earbuds or earphones connected to iPods.  Each person heard his or her own loud music, but no one could hear anybody else's music.  Any onlooker without an iPod would have deemed the gathering silent.

Answer (score 1):

In Jamaica, they have(/had?) street parties where different groups would bring amplifiers and speakers (a "sound system") and DJs/MCs, each competing against each other for the crowd's attention and to draw the crowd to their area, where they would also sell them drink/food etc. Obviously one of the ways of gaining the crowd's attention over a rival crew is to simply have a sound system that is way louder than theirs; and crews would put a lot of effort into developing their systems to make them as loud as possible. This idea migrated to the UK and is particularly common in the drum'n'bass/jungle scene, where if a particular sound system has a good reputation it would act as a draw for crowds as much as a DJ line-up. To illustrate the emphasis on volume, the power rating of the amplifiers is often mentioned when publicising a particular system (with higher meaning better!)

So, in answer to your question, "sound-system-loud" connotes very, very, very, very, very loud.